# How to render views inside page-front.tpl.php?

Tags: views

I have a view named 'Updates' which displays latest article. How to render this view directly in my tpl.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
print views_embed_view('my_view', 'block_1', $arg1);
?>
```

- replace **view_name** with your view name
- replace **block_1** with your [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)
- replace **$arg1** with an argument (if want to manually pass a value to your contextual filter) This is optional, if you're not going to use it, you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

For this, there are two options that you can use.

1. Make the view as block and assign this block in any region as per your need.
2. You can use [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) function.

Comment: Thanks Atul, I didn't wanted to use block as I'm theming bootstrap from scratch and I need to learn more on the context. Thanks anyways bruh