# Alternative views on content type

Tags: 7, views, nodes

How do you allow a content type to publish an option that changes views options of that page?

I have created 2 views slideshows block with different settings - I want the user to choose how to view the images on any page of a certain content type BUT DONT WANT TO SAVE THE PAGES TWICE - the images must be shown programmatically depending on which view option is chosen.

I saw this [tutorial](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192960/how-to-render-views-inside-page-front-tpl-php#192962) on rendering views via a tpl.php file...

I do not know how to create and where to place this tpl.php file -- Could this be implemented as a module instead?
What do you place in the $args function - are there any useful examples?

Answer (score 3):

Add a new field to your content type:

- Name: **Pick a view**
- Type: **boolean**
- Widget: [doesn't matter]

Then add this code to your block or node or page tpl.php file.

```
<?php

if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = $node->nid;

$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$field_value = $wrapper->field_pick_a_view->value();

if ($field_value == 1) {
  print views_embed_view('my_view', 'block_1'); 
  } else { 
  print views_embed_view('my_view', 'block_2');
  }
}

?>
```

- replace **view_name** with your view name
- replace **block_1** or **block_2** with your [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)

So if your field is check-marked, it prints view 1. If it's not checked-marked, it prints view 2.

Comment: Thanks! - I have added this to my /modules/system/page.tpl.php file - is that correct? Do I change anything in the boolean field settings? Also, in the manage display I have changed the label to 'above' and format to 'default'

Comment: @ldvt5 incorrect, as when you update Drupal core your file will get overriden. You need to put it in `/sites/all/themes/[your theme]/templates` folder. If there is no page.tpl.php file there, copy over the one from system and add the changes.

Comment: If you want you could create an empty block, then create a tpl file for it **block--block--[block-id].tpl.php** (you can get the block id number from the configure block url). Example: `admin/structure/block/manage/block/8/configure` would be `block--block--8.tpl.php`

Comment: I have added the code to the my theme's page.php.tpl file but no luck (I have made sure the views and block names are correct)


I have also tried to add that code to a blank block using the php filtering in the WYSIWYG
(https://www.drupal.org/node/1046700)


If I go ahead with the creation of 'block--block--[block-id].tpl.php' do I place it under the same /sites/all/themes/[your theme]/templates folder?


Anything else I can check to troubleshoot?

Comment: `/sites/all/themes/[your theme]/templates folder` yep same place, all your templates should go there. `Anything else I can check to troubleshoot?` try using this code alone `print views_embed_view('my_view', 'block_1');` to see if you can print the view. Also, are you using a contextual filter in your view?

Comment: IT WORKS!!! However I may mis-placed the question - I need the checkbox on  the published page (not whilst editing the page) For example Unauthenticated users can change how the content is displayed and (of course) they would not be able to edit the page!

Comment: Then you have to use jQuery, to create a fake link, so when it gets clicked it ajax loads the other view and renames the link. Also, you may want to add a cookie, so it remembers what view is suppose to show if the page gets refreshed.